# joomla: Changes that I make to template_css.css are not showing up on site

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

**PROBLEM**: I make changes to template_css.css, but those changes do not show up on website.

**1** - I have tested the website on multiple browsers.

**2** - I have cleared the browser cache on all of them.

**3** - I have turned off *Administrator/SEO-Settings/Search-Engine-Friendly-URLs*

**4** - I do not see an .htaccess file in the site's directory

**5** - I can download the css file to my computer (via ftp), **but cannot upload to that directory** ... 755 permissions ... the site is on my webhost account that I have been using for many years.

**6** - I am able to change&save the `template_css.css` (via *Administrator/Template Manager/Customize Template/Stylesheets/edit css/template_css.css*), and then download the css to my computer (via ftp) and verify that the change did succeed.

**7** - **I can navigate to the css file directly (via my browser), and it shows the OLD values.**

**8** - I can arbitrarily change the name of the `template_css.css` (via my ftp client), and the *Administrator/Template Manager/Customize Template/Stylesheets/* will reflect the changed name.

**9** - I can examine the html via firebug, and the css for the element in question indicates the correct css file: `www.my_site.com/templates/pinboard_av_j17/css/template_css.css` ... but it shows the OLD values.

**10** - I can rename the .css file (via my ftp client), and then navigate to the old filename (via browser (with cleared cache)), and it will still show the .css file (with the old values).

The site is: [b4x.si](http://www.b4x.si)

---

**EDIT:** this morning I repeated #7 (navigated directly to the css file) and noticed that the css file has been updated *so apparently at some point many hours after making the changes in the template manager, the css finally updated*.

However, please keep in mind that initially after making the changes, if I ftp'd the css file to my computer that I Could see the changes (#6), but if I navigated directly to the css file via browser that I could Not see the changes (#7).

---

Comment: Are you working on a copy or the original template?

Comment: Are the desired values being overridden by any of the core css entries?

Comment: @Elin ... I am working on template_css.css, which I find within my template's css folder ...

Comment: @user3295190 ... I do not think that that is it because of #7 ... I suppose that if I could navigate to the css file, and see updated values, but not see those updated values on the website (presuming cleared browser cache), then I could assume that possibly joomla was adding some additional runtime 'rendering' layer to the site.

Comment: please see my edit to the original post

Comment: Is there any published cache plugin on your website? See in the plugin manager

Comment: I am aware of  `System - Cache` via `Plug-in Manager`, but it is disabled. And its option, Use Browser Caching, is set to No.

Comment: have you installed a third party cache like jotcache or something? The description of your issue realy makes me think of a cache issue. The other option is that your webhoster is caching files for you (some of them do) try to find out about that.

Comment: question: is there a procedural way to go through any and all modules/plugins to determine if they have some kind of cache-control? ... ... I did a simple keyword search in Plug-in Manager for 'cache' and it only found the System-Cache ... but there could be others whose names do not match the 'cache' string.

Comment: It really sounds like you are editing one copy but the site is using a different copy, which is why I asked.  Most of the time when this happens to me it is because I had made a copy of the template to make changes in and then I edit the wrong copy of the file or the index.php has hard coded references to the folder where the original copy was.

Comment: @elin ... yeah I was thinking about that also ... however I can simultaneously **A)** open my ftp directly to that .css file (and download it my my local machine to look at it), and **B)** open my browser to that same file, but **C)** they will _initially_ (for apparently several hours) show different contents.

Comment: @elin ... I just repeated the steps to verify my earlier response, and it does indeed behave as I suggested ... ... **1)** I made one simple change to template_css.css via Template Manager, **2)** ftp'd that file to my local machine to look at it, **3)** also browsed to that css file to look at it in browser, **4)** the downloaded file Does have the change, the browser version does Not.

Comment: Which is why I am saying it seems like there are two different files. Are you positive you never made a copy of the template? Can you please paste the line from index.php that includes that file?

Comment: this is from the index.php file that I find within my /templates/my_template/ ... `<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` ... ....